# How to create a customized matrix in R where first few columns are zero and rest are an Identity Matrix?

Tags: arrays, r

Suppose we have a matrix `A` of order `k2*k` where `k=k1+k2` such that `k1=k-k2`. The characteristic of the matrix `A` is such that first `k1` columns are zero and remaining `k2*k2` is an identity matrix. How to create such a customized matrix in R?

**NOTE:**

For smaller dimensions of `k1` and `k2`, it's easy. But I am looking for an automated command for handling larger dimensions of `k1` and `k2`.

Comment: For `k1=2` and `k2=3`, I am using `=matrix(c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1),ncol=5)`.

Comment: Why don't you create your identity matrix first (use diag(k2)), and add the remaining columns and rows with cbind and rbind?

Comment: That's great @Rodrigo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
k <- 20
k2 <- 15
k1 <- k - k2

diagonal <- diag(k2)
zeros <- matrix(0, nrow = k2, ncol = k1)

result <- cbind(zeros, diagonal)
```